# codeigniter url routing 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Good Day Friends
I am working on Codeigniter Site. I have a url like this

```
http://localhost/index.php/Medical/college/in/haryana
```

but i want

```
http://localhost/index.php/medical_college_in_haryana
```

Is it possible.

**What I have tried**

```
$route['medical/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'medical_$1_in_$2';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288258/codeigniter-routing?rq=1 this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Your condition doesn't match because it's not case insensitive.

```
$route['(?i)medical/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'medical_$1_in_$2';
```

the (?i) says to match Medical, mEDiCal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$route[':any'] = 'controller/method';
```

in function

```
$var = explode("_", $this->uri->segment(1));
print_r(current($var));
```